# angular add unsafe before url in href - sanitizing unsafe URL

Tags: android, angular, angular6

I am trying to open an app. Its working fine when I give a static URL. But as I create a dynamic href tag in *ngFor I can see unsafe keyword is added before the URL and it's not working.

I am running on Angular 6. And getting the Id in a service. In ngFor I am looping the result and creating a link with Id to open the app. I create a pipe but it's still not working.

**Safe Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeurl'
})
export class SafeurlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: any) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
  }

}
```

In the component I added the below line between ngFor tag

```
<a href="appName://joinTournament?id={{t.tag}} |safeurl">Join</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use your pipe within interpolation. With your way it's just a string (part of href). It means, angular does not recognize it as a pipe or part of your application. Also, you need to bind the value itself only and nothing else. In your case you can pass `appName://joinTournament?id=` as a parameter to the pipe.

Here is a [working solution.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1cqo3q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsafe-url.pipe.ts)

Add another parameter to your pipe as follows

```
transform(value: any, prefix = '') {
  return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(prefix + value);
}
```

And change

```
<a href="appName://joinTournament?id={{t.tag}} |safeurl">Join</a>
```

to

```
<a [href]="t.tag | safeurl: 'appName://joinTournament?id='">Join</a>
```

Comment: I tired but now its showing .  sanitizing unsafe URL value clashroyale://joinTournament?id=SafeValue

Comment: @Waqas yes, I saw that and I've updated my answer with a working blitz.