# Ionic 4 cannot display photo taken by phone

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am taking a photo on the phone using

```
takePicture(){
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     this.photo = this.webView.convertFileSrc(imageData)
  }, (err) => {
   // Handle error
  });
```

Before passing to the convertFileSrc the image URL looks like

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4889FE26-A26C-42AE-9EF2-D5FAE0ECBE10/tmp/cdv_photo_007.jpg
```

But when I run this I get this warning message:

```
WARN: WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value ionic://localhost/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4889FE26-A26C-42AE-9EF2-D5FAE0ECBE10/tmp/cdv_photo_007.jpg
```

and the image does not display. I am trying to display it on a page like this:

```
   <img *ngIf="photo!=null" src={{photo}}/>
```

what do I need to do to the url to display it in the page?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356076/angular-add-unsafe-before-url-in-href-sanitizing-unsafe-url/54356126#54356126

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,) {}

takePicture(){
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.webView.convertFileSrc(imageData));
  }, (err) => {
   // Handle error
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the `DomSanitizer`:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
    private webview: WebView,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

public getImgContent(imageName: string): SafeResourceUrl {
 return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.webview.convertFileSrc(this.file.dataDirectory + imageName));
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<img [src]="getImgContent(imageName)">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
takePicture(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
       this.photo = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imageData);
       console.log("fewf",this.photo)
          }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    });
  }
```

It works for me.